# UITextField inside XIB / NIB does not show Copy, Paste, etc. context menu

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

I want to use `UITextFields` inside of a `UICollectionView` and i have the problem that the textfields do not show a context menu. Normally outside of the collection view the textfields show a context menu when the user clicks / touches long inside of the textfield. Inside of the collection view the behaviour gets lost.

Here is my code in an simple example.
`ViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var cv: UICollectionView!

    let string_array : [String] = [
        "test",
        "test2",
        "test3"
    ]

    var sizingTextFieldCell : TextFieldCell?
    var textfieldCellNib : UINib = UINib(nibName: "TextFieldCell", bundle: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.sizingTextFieldCell = (textfieldCellNib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil) as NSArray).firstObject as! TextFieldCell?

        self.cv.register(self.textfieldCellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TextFieldCell")

        self.cv.delegate = self
        self.cv.dataSource = self
    }
}

// UICollectionView DataSource
extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    // count of columns
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    // count of cell items
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return string_array.count
    }

    // content of the cell items
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let form_element_index = indexPath.row    // index of the collectionView cell

        let cell : TextFieldCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TextFieldCell", for: indexPath) as! TextFieldCell

        cell.textfield.text = string_array[form_element_index]

        return cell
    }
}

// UICollectionView DelegateFlowLayout
extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    // wenn ich die funktion entferne haben alle elemente nur noch die minimalgröße
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let form_element_index = indexPath.row    // index of the collectionView cell

        self.sizingTextFieldCell!.textfield.text = string_array[form_element_index]

        return self.sizingTextFieldCell!.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
    }
}
```

`TextFieldCell.swift`:

```
import UIKit

class TextFieldCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textfield: UITextField!

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        self.textfield.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1, alpha: 1)           // black text color
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5                                                                 // radius 4

        textfield.delegate = self as! UITextFieldDelegate
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        //super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        self.textfield.becomeFirstResponder()
        //self.next?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool
    {
        return true
    }
}
```

Has anyone an idea what can be done to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just wanted to add that i am using iOS 10.3.1 on my iPhone 7+.

Comment: iOS Development Target is iOS 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I downloaded the project provided by @cylov:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1w1Ti0xMEZXaFo4RGJHUDAtTFU/view

I realised that the root view in the TextField.xib file provided by him is a UIView whereas it is supposed to be UICollectionView. This must have happened because of adding the xib file separately after adding TexField.xib. Making UIView behave as a UICollectionViewCell perhaps created an unexpected behaviour.

**1st approach**

When you add a new file (subclassing UICollectionViewCell), mark the checkbox saying: ***Also create xib***

**2nd approach**

Another approach to the solution would have been to delete the root view present in xib file and drag drop a brand new UICollectionViewCell and start afresh.
This definitely fixes the issue.

**ANSWER THAT DID NOT WORK**

1. I tried following your code and figured out that the following dataSource method of UICollectionView was not getting called:

   ```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
   ```

Fixed this by replacing

```
return self.sizingTextFieldCell!.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
```

with

```
return CGSize(width: 251.0, height: 50.0)
```

2. Now later on I tried long tapping a text field on the collection view, I was able to get the context menu.

I am attaching screenshots related to the same.[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I changed my code but I'm still not getting the context menu pop up.

Comment: Your version show that is possible to have this context menu popup inside of collection views. But i still don't know why your version is working and my version is not.

Comment: Did you use an extra xib file for the definition of the collection view cell? Or did you define the cell inside to the collection view in the storyboard?

Comment: I used a xib file for the cell.

Comment: Could you upload this project somewhere like Google drive and share a link  to download and investigate the issue?

Comment: Hello Saurabh, here is the link to my project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1w1Ti0xMEZXaFo4RGJHUDAtTFU

Comment: Hi, I tried matching the settings of UITextField in your TextFieldCell.xib with mine, but it diddn't work. Then I simply replaced your version of xib file with mine and it worked.
On further investigation, I realised that the root view in my xib file is a UICollectionView but in your case it's UIView. This must have happened because you added the xib file separately after adding TexField.xib. Making UIView behave as a UICollectionViewCell perhaps is creating an unexpected behaviour. So, when you add a new file (subclassing UICollectionViewCell), mark the checkbox saying: Also create xib.

Comment: @cyclov: Accept the answer too, if it helped.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!! I removed the TextField.xib file from the project and added a new version of it. Before the deletion i checked from which classes the views inherit. The main view in the xib inherits from class TextFieldCell which inherits from UICollectionViewCell. And the child of the mainview inherits from UITextField. I cannot see where i inherited just only from UIView. After adding the new xib the copy / paste is still not working... I will upload the new project again!

Comment: here is the new project upload: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1w1Ti0xMEZXMjZIZ0pHekFOZ28

Comment: looking up the xib file in source code mode is showing the main view is of the type TextFieldCell: `<view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="iN0-l3-epB" customClass="TextFieldCell"...` TextFieldCell does inherit from UICollectionViewCell: `class TextFieldCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate`

Comment: Sorry for not up voting your answer. It hasn't solved the problem yet.

Comment: Just to let you know. Your help finally solved the problem! I created the TextFieldCell.swift and TextFieldCell.xib separaetly. Now i created then via File -> New -> File... -> Cocoa Touch Class -> Class: TextFieldCell with also create XIB File checked. Thanks a lot and have a nice day! Greets Cylov :-)

Comment: @cyclov: Sorry for the late reply. Good to know that your problem is solved.
Just to give you more insight into this, I would like you to follow these steps:

1. Open the xib file and select the root view and open the Identity Inspector on the right. Delete the contents of custom class text field and you'll see the base class of the UI element. This is how I investigated the issue.

2. Another way as mentioned in answer is to delete the root view present in xib file and drag drop a brand new UICollectionViewCell. In the Identity Inspector mention TextFieldCell against Custom Class.

Comment: Happy to help :)